# Retrieve only one record with different variants in Django Database/models using sqlite3

Tags: json, django-models, django-queryset, django-database

In my database I have these 3 records under title fields. They have different IDs.

```
    { "result": [ { 
    "id": "32b05a2f-e52f-55c6-8314-090bdd82e588",
    "movie": {"advisory_rating": "PG", 
    "canonical_title": "(3D/4DX)GEOSTORM", 
    "cast": [ "Jeremy Ray Taylor", "Gerard Butler", "Abbie Cornish" ], 
    "poster_portait": "http://www.sureseats.com/images/events/movies/thumbnails/geostorm.gif", 
    "release_date": "", "synopis": "Synopsis Here" } 
    },
    { 
    "id": "c5f681bd-134e-544e-bdfe-04b76d6002ae",
    "movie": {"advisory_rating": "PG", "canonical_title": "(ATMOS)GEOSTORM", 
    "cast": [ "Jeremy Ray Taylor", "Gerard Butler", "Abbie Cornish" ], 
    "poster_portait": "http://www.sureseats.com/images/events/movies/thumbnails/geostorm.gif", 
    "release_date": "", "synopis": "Synopsis Here" }
    },
    { 
    "id": "88da30ec-2e63-540a-80e1-d67c14978fb1",
    "movie": {"advisory_rating": "PG", "canonical_title": "GEOSTORM", 
    "cast": [ "Jeremy Ray Taylor", "Gerard Butler", "Abbie Cornish" ], 
    "poster_portait": "http://www.sureseats.com/images/events/movies/thumbnails/geostorm.gif", 
    "release_date": "", "synopis": "Synopsis Here" } },
```

They are different records but since they are the same movie I should only get one records (Geostorm). How can I query that to my views.py in Django. Thank you. I use sqlite3 as my database.

Answer (score 0):

## dry

by using get you will get only one object now you can take

```
movie=ModelName.objects.get(movie='advisory_rating')
```

you can get title by movie.canonical_title